# Adding a WFS with ajax from Geoserver using Openlayers3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, ajax

I am trying to load vector with the following code:

```
 var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
      loader: function(extent) {
       $.ajax('http://************/geoserver/Viva/ows', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.1.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typename: 'Viva:building',
            srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
            bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326'

          }
        }).done(function(response) {
          sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
       },
```

I don`t seem to be able to get any features. I have a suspicion that I am not setting the typename right. The data is points of buildings.

The url in the geoserver preview layer is the following:

http://************/geoserver/Viva/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Viva:building&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=text.

I have tested loading a GeoJson layer and it works without fail from the same server and data by using the url-method.

The end goal is to add a new point with WFS-t.

I got most of my code from this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/h7mk0jpt/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=h7mk0jpt

**Update:**

I have changed the ol.format.WFS like follow:

```
var formatWFS = ol.format.WFS({
featureNS: "http://serverURL:8080/geoserver/vivadata",
featureType: "Viva:buildingType"
                                    });
```

and I get the following error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeTransaction' of undefined at transactWFS

This is the block of code for transactWFS:

```
var transactWFS = function(mode, a) {
      var node;
      switch (mode) {
        case 'insert':
          node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([a], null, null, formatGML);
          break;
        case 'update':
          node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [a], null, formatGML);
          break;
        case 'delete':
          node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [a], formatGML);
          break;
      }
```

and this is my draw function:

```
var DrawControl = function(opt_options) {
        var options = opt_options || {};
        this.active = options.active || false;
        var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            source: options.source,
            type: 'Point',
            geometryName: 'geom'

        });
        draw.on('drawstart', function(t) {
        buildingLayer.set('selectable',false);
      });

        //Sets building properties when addBuilding-button isclicked
        draw.on('drawend', function(t) {
        var a = t.feature;
        a.setProperties({

            prim_add: document.getElementById('inpPriAddress').value,
            sec_add: document.getElementById('inpSecAddress').value,
            tert_add: document.getElementById('inpTerAddress').value,
            build_type:document.getElementById('inpBuildingType').value,
            build_mat:document.getElementById('inpBuildingMaterial').value,
            build_own: document.getElementById('inpHouseOwner').value,
        })
        transactWFS('insert', a);
        buildingLayer.set('selectable',true);
      });
```

Comment: Check the order of coordinates in bbox, it should be latitude-longitude for EPSG:4326 if you use WFS 1.1.0.

Comment: also your BBOX will be in the map's SRS not necessarily 4326

Comment: I am also facing same issue sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long struggle and reimplementation of my Geoserver, I found the settings that allow WFS-t on the server's side.